# Prove that $q$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Problem**
>
> If $a$, $b$, $q=\left(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}\right)$ are natural numbers, then $q$ is a perfect square. Are there infinitely many $\left(a,b,q\right)$ triplets?

I have tried to prove the problem assuming that $q$ is not a perfect square and hoped to get some contradiction but unfortunately I can't seem to get it. Regarding the second part of the problem, I think that probably it is not true. In case it is true I add the following problem to the original statement.

> Can there be found expressions for $a$, $b$ and $q$ such that it generates an infinitely many (but not necessarily all) such triplets?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: peterwhy's example shows that it is false. Perhaps $a,b>0$?

Comment: See also http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Problems.html.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the link. But What about the number of examples?

Comment: Since you are looking for $q\in\mathbb{Z}$, you need to determine when $1+ab|a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @KSmarts: I can't see how to do it.

Comment: What happens if $a=0$?

Comment: natural numbers are positive integers: $1,2,3,4,...$. By definition, that excludes peterwhy's example. If domain was integers, then he has a perfect counter-example.

Comment: @Integrator: Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=0$. Then
$$
q=\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}=\frac{0+b^2}{1+0}=b^2
$$
Also, since $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, you know that $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and that $q$ is a perfect square. Therefore, for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, the triplet $(0,x,x^2)$ satisfies the requirements. So does $(x,0,x^2)$.

There are others, too, but you don't need to find them, since there are infinitely many already.

Restricting $a,b,q>0$, as per your edit, makes things a bit trickier. I'm still working on it, but I've only found the rather trivial $(1,1,1)$ so far.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @user170039 I have changed my answer accordingly. It doesn't really affect much.

Comment: @user170039 Wait... are you considering $0$ to be a natural number or not?

Comment: Of course $0$ is not a Natural Number.